# Where should I generate Windows Terminal JSON fragment extensions?

Tags: windows-terminal

I'm creating "JSON fragment extensions" for Windows Terminal in my code, to create some "auto-generated" Windows Terminal profiles.

In the official docs, [JSON fragment extensions in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/json-fragment-extensions), there are 2 locations recommended for storing fragments (if your application is not a Microsoft Store app):

> For applications installed from the web, there are 2 cases.
> The first is that the installation is for all the users on the system. In this case, the JSON files should be added to the folder:
>
> `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments\{app-name}\{file-name}.json`
>
> In the second case, the installation is only for the current user. In this case, the JSON files should be added to the folder:
>
> `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments\{app-name}\{file-name}.json`

This seems straightforward enough, but there's [some other documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install#settings-json-file) that describes the actual *settings.json* file location:

> The path for your Windows Terminal settings.json file may be found in one of the following directories:
>
> - Terminal (stable / general release): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`
> - Terminal (preview release): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json`
> - Terminal (unpackaged: Scoop, Chocolately, etc): `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\settings.json`

So, to be clear, these paths are not important if I'm creating profile fragment files, right? I don't need to choose a different path (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe` vs `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe` vs `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows Terminal`) **for the Fragments files** because Fragments will always be loaded from `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments` etc?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, to be clear, these paths are not important if I'm creating profile fragment files, right?

Correct! The locations Terminal looks for fragment files are well-defined and durable across different versions.